# ClickOnce installation issue after Windows 10 Update

Tags: c#, vb.net, clickonce

I have strange behaviour. After most recent Windows 10 update all users of my aplication which just installed the update cannot open their clickonce application. Behaviour is when each of them trying to run app, it immediatly closes. It's always the same for each of user who installed last update. Does anyone knows why it happens and how to solve that issue?

Comment: You'll need to add more information in order for this to be answered.  If you can't debug the app on a machine experiencing the problem then look in the Windows application event logs to get more information.  Also, add logging to your application.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickonce App Doesn't start with Windows 1803](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379742/clickonce-app-doesnt-start-with-windows-1803)

Answer (score 4):

We have the same issue with apps that are not signed with a code signing certificate.

After installing the latest version of Windows 10 (1803), ClickOnce just blocks the app, instead of warning the user and letting them open it anyway.

To see if that is your issue, try disabling the SmartScreen in Windows for these kinds of apps:

Under "App & browser control" set the category "Check apps and files" to "Off".

This solution in obviously not very nice but I'm not sure how to fix it other than signing the software.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to get around this problem without disabling SmartScreen is to add the URL of your ClickOnce app to your Trusted Sites in "Internet Options" in Control Panel.

[image: Internet Properties]

Another option is to sign you ClickOnce app with a CA-issued certificate, but then you have to install the cert in your user's Trusted Publishers certificate store.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/how-to-add-a-trusted-publisher-to-a-client-computer-for-clickonce-applications

Answer (score 1):

Try to run application directly from network share. If it will not run too, then problem is not in ClickOnce.

By the way, I strongly do not recommend deploying using ClickOnce monstrosity. I have the worst experiences with it.

Comment: What you process? Choosing Clickonce i can publish in one place for all users.

Comment: If it is in intranet, shared folder and shadow copying is much better than ClickOnce.

Answer (score 1):

Go to %appdata%\local\apps\2.0\XXXX\XXXX\ and find where your app runs locally and run it from there. Windows will prompt you stating it doesn’t trust the application. Give it permission there and it will run from then on. This is a quick and dirty way to fix the issue as I just ran into this issue last week.

Answer (score 0):

I found if I went to %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0(whatever the clickonce applicaiton subpath was) and found the .exe file for the application, right clicked on it, chose "properties", it was showing with the "this file has been downloaded from the internet and might not be trusted" thing at the bottom of the general tab. There was an "unblock" button, so I clicked that and it stopped prompting for the windows store. YMMV of course.