# Click Once app is not running after installation

Tags: clickonce

I have a c# click once app.

when i run it in visual studio it works fine.

When i install it and run it, the launching app windows appears and closes after 2 second.

When I run the Exe file from the click once installation folder it works.

The strange thing is that it works on some computers (including mine) and on some it has the behavior i described above.

Where can I see the logs of the click once?

## UPDATE

when change the App and browser control -> check app and files from warning to off it works but i can't change it for the clients computer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickonce App Doesn't start with Windows 1803](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379742/clickonce-app-doesnt-start-with-windows-1803)