# Company Applications Won't Start After Update

Tags: vb.net, clickonce

I am running into an issue with ClickOnce applications (VB) after they have been updated. In the past when Applications in my office are updated everyone would run the application, be prompted to update, it would update, a brief loading bar shows up, and the application would start up just fine.

Recently when the applications have been updated, about half of the office can successfully update and use the application, but for the other half the application updates and after the update is complete the application doesn't start up and cannot open from any desktop, start menu, or taskbar icons (no error message, just doesn't start up). The only way they can use the application is to go through the Local folder in UserName>AppData and run the .exe file. At that point the application starts up and after that it can be started from any icon until the next update.

Why would the application run from the .exe file, but not from any icons? And why does running it from the .exe file fix it until the next update? I cannot figure out why half of the office is running into this problem while updating works perfectly fine for the other half. Everyone has administrator privileges and it does not seem to be an OS issue. Any help or insight on this would be great.

Comment: I've got the same problem with our ClickOnce app. Seems like it does not work for colleagues who installed the Windows 10 April 2018 update (version 1803). Can you confirm that in your office?

Comment: Another workaround to get over the first run is to temporarily disable SmartScreen in _Windows Defender Security Center_ / _App & browser control_ / _Check apps and files_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clickonce App Doesn't start with Windows 1803](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50379742/clickonce-app-doesnt-start-with-windows-1803)

Comment: @JosefBláha You are correct. It doesn't work for colleagues who installed the April 2018 update (but not only on Windows 10, we have at least one Windows 7 user who is running into the issue). The ones who are not affected do not have Windows defender running at all but I'm weary of the Windows Defender workaround because it could create a security risk moving forward.

Comment: Correction, the Windows 7 user is not experiencing the issue...